# How to find data from CouchBaseLite Mobile using query?

Tags: ios, swift3, couchbase-lite

my document

```
let properties: [String : Any] = [
            "project_id":Task.project_id!,
            "title": title,
            "parent_id": parent_id,
            "weight": "1",
            "created_at": DateTime.DateTime(),
            "updated_at": DateTime.DateTime(),
            "type": "group",
            "tag_id":tagId,
            "owner": Session.username!,
        ]
```

I want to find data according to condition.

I mean, I want to get which document where parent_id is not nil("") or null. 
 I am using this query

```
func setupViewAndQuery() {

    let listsView = database.viewNamed("list/GroupDropDown")

    if listsView.mapBlock == nil {
        listsView.setMapBlock({ (doc, emit) in
            if let type: String = doc["type"] as? String, let name = doc["title"], let parent_id = doc["parent_id"] as? String, let created  = doc["created_at"], let updated = doc["updated_at"], let Id = doc["_id"]
                , type == "group", parent_id != "" {
                emit([name,parent_id,created,updated,Id], nil)
            }
        }, version: "1.0")
    }

    listsLiveQuery = listsView.createQuery().asLive()
    listsLiveQuery.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rows", options: .new, context: nil)
    listsLiveQuery.start()
}
```

but this function returns all data. how to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view that only emits entries when the parent_id is not nil.

Alternatively, you could look at with [groupLevel](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html#creating-and-configuring-queries) can give you what you want.  This would involve using a reduce function, and doesn't seem to quite fit with your structure.  It would require some reworking of your map function.

Otherwise you can just filter out rows as you iterate over the query results.